# Amount of possible Matrix multiplications per frame?

Tags: matrix, 3d, gpu, rendering

I want to know how many matrices a top tier graphics card can multiply. I am talking about 4x4 projection/view matrices, no lighting whatsoever. Also, I do not want an exact number but more like a general direction in which this is going.

Thanks!